# Handling of tautomerism in QSAR modelling

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

This article from 2009:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2776169/

mentions the potential impact of tautomerism on QSAR modelling, and concludes that more work is needed to address it.

**12 years later, what is the consensus in the cheminformatics community regarding this (i.e. regarding how tautomerism should be handled when doing QSAR modelling)? Or in fact, is there a consensus at all?**

I found only scattered later contributions on the topic.

This one:

https://www.simulations-plus.com/assets/RFraczkiewicz-QSAR_Modeling_Independent_of_Input_Tautomer-GCCh-2015.pdf

seems to argue that the solution is to create tautomer-independent descriptors.

This one:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00044-013-0776-0

seems to be more focused on the analysis of the problem than on suggesting solutions.
[But I have not read it yet, I will see if I can get it].

Several other papers argue that the solution is to convert all molecules to a 'standard' tautomeric form, and they even provide large sets of transformations to apply.

Personally, I have no trouble believing that 'some' approach based on special descriptors or standard tautomer forms may work *better* than most on specific cases (specific molecular properties to predict), but *I am wondering if any such approaches are theoretically/fundamentally justified*, or just approximations.

Take for instance logD_7.4. You can measure this property by shaking a compound in a biphasic mixture of water and 2-octanol buffered at pH 7.4, taking samples from the two layers and finding the concentrations of compound in them. logD_7.4 is then the log10 of the ratio of the 2-octanol / water concentrations.
However, if the compound has 2 possible (and rapidly interconverting) tautomeric forms, each with its own concentration in the two layers, in fact the concentrations we measure are the sums of the concentrations of the two tautomers (assuming the analytical method does not discriminate the tautomers). Then 3 constants are necessary to describe the existing equilibria, and the 'experimental' logD_7.4 is in fact a combination of these constants. We are measuring the logD_7.4 of a *mixture*, not of an individual chemical species.
If this is true, how can representing one single tautomer and associating it to one single measurement referred to mixture be a correct way to handle this situation?
But OK, this is only my view; I'd be glad to be wrong, because that would make our modelling work much easier :)